# T-SQL Query Performance Optimization

Tags: t-sql

This query shows how many stolen and recovered vehicles there were based on county and date range. I have a query that works on small data sets, but when I run it on the actual data (several million records) it takes way too long to run. I was wondering if there is another way I could write this query to be more efficient. I think my issue is when I join the agency table with 'or' to compare the agency primary keys with the Thefts table. Any input would be appreciated.

```
    Thefts Table:                                                  County Table:        Agency Table:

    TheftAgencyPK: TheftDate:  RecoveryAgencypk: RecoveryDate:     PK:    Name:        PK  Name:
          1        2019-05-01          1         2019-05-02         1    Sacramento    1   SacPD 
          1        2019-05-02          2         2019-05-04         2    Aptos         2   AptosPD 
          1        2019-05-03          1         2019-05-05
          2        2019-05-05          1         2019-05-09
          1        2019-01-01          2         2019-05-01
```

```
Select 
    sub.CountyName 
    ,Sum(Case When sub.TheftDate Between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-31' and sub.Agency = sub.TheftAgency Then 1  Else 0 End) As Thefts 
    ,Sum(Case When sub.RecoveryDate Between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-31' and sub.Agency = sub.RecoveryAgency then 1 else 0 end) as Recoveries
From
    (Select 
         Theft.TheftDate as TheftDate, Theft.TheftAgencyPK as TheftAgency,  
         Theft.RecoveryDate as RecoveryDate, 
         Theft.RecoveryAgencyPK as RecoveryAgency, Agency.pk as Agency, 
         County.PK as CountyPK, County.name as CountyName 
     From 
         Thefts Theft
     Left Join 
         Agency Agency on Agency.pk = Theft.TheftAgencyPK or Agency.pk = Theft.RecoveryAgencyPK
     Inner Join 
         County County on County.PK = Agency.pk
     Where 
         TheftDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-31' 
         or RecoveryDate between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-01') Sub
Group By 
    sub.CountyName
```

Output:

```
   CountyName:     Thefts:      Recoveries:
   ----------------------------------------
      Aptos           1             2
      Sacramento      4             3
```

Comment: You'll need to give us the DDL of the tables, along with their indexes, and the execution plan for us to begin to help you here

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. Tip: Always use table aliases in complex queries. The `where` clause gets columns from somewhere. but it isn't clear what table(s) they are in.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ORs by changing the structure of your SQL. However I am not sure what your result really means. You sum over county, with recovery agency and theft agency, however, the you compare to the "agency" column which is taken primarily from theftagency.

I would suggest something like this, which first sums thefts pr agency, and then recoveries pr agency, and then sums it up by county, by which county the theft was in and which county the recovery as in. This ensures that the result is pr county.

```
SELECT
    County.Name
    ,sum(a.Thefts) Thefts
    ,sum(a.Recoveries) Recoveries
FROM (SELECT
        Theft.TheftAgencyPK AS Agency
       ,COUNT(*) Thefts
       ,0 AS Recoveries
    FROM Thefts Theft
    WHERE Theft.TheftDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-05-31'
    GROUP BY Theft.TheftAgencyPK
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Theft.RecoveryAgencyPK AS Agency
       ,0 AS Thefts
       ,COUNT(*) AS Recoveries
    FROM Thefts Theft
    WHERE RecoveryDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-05-01'
    GROUP BY Theft.RecoveryAgencyPK) a
LEFT JOIN Agency Agency
    ON Agency.pk = a.Agency
INNER JOIN County County
    ON County.PK = Agency.pk
```

Performance wise the heavy lifting is done in the union all- If you have indexes on the Thefts table on theft and recovery date, this might give you an ok performance.

It would most likely lead to two passes of the Thefts table, which might be ok, depending on size and indexing strategy.

If you want just one pass you might do something like this instead of the union all, this might force the optimizer to do just one pass of the thefts table:

```
SELECT
    IIF(t = 'theft', Theft.TheftAgencyPK, Theft.RecoveryAgencyPK) AS Agency
   ,SUM(IIF(t = 'theft', 1, 0)) AS Thefts
   ,SUM(IIF(t = 'theft', 0, 1)) AS Recoveries
FROM Thefts Theft
INNER JOIN (SELECT
        'theft' t UNION ALL SELECT
        'recovery' t) t
    ON (t = 'theft'
            AND Theft.TheftDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-05-31')
        OR (t = 'recovery'
            AND Theft.RecoveryDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-05-31')
GROUP BY IIF(t = 'theft', Theft.TheftAgencyPK, Theft.RecoveryAgencyPK)
```